# How can I split router.js in SailsJS

Tags: routes, sails.js

My project is getting larger and router.js is growing too. Is it possible to split it into several different route files? Each route file applies to a different controller.

Comment: btw, whoever voted to close this question should stick to patrolling topics they actually understand. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sails, you can put your routes in any file in `config/`, as long as you export `module.exports.routes`. So you can do something like this:

#### 1. config/routes.js

```
module.exports.routes = { };
```

#### 2. config/routes/otherRoute.js

```
_.defaults(sails.config.routes, {
  // other routes
});
```

Comment: I am trying it but not getting succeed. Is there any other way to this?

Comment: answer doesn't seem to work because globals like _ and sails are not accessible

Answer (score 3):

I've included my custom routes in my API folder. I've created a folder api/routes/ and include my custom routes like:

### 1. config/routes.js

```
var routes = require('../api/routes/Route');
var contact = require('../api/routes/ContactRoute');

var all = routes.custom;

var contactsRoutes = contact.contactRoutes;

// Dynamic include custom routes from api
var routes = function (dic) {
  var obj = {};
  dic.forEach(function (routes) {
    for (p in routes) {
      obj[p] = routes[p];
    }
  })

  return obj;
}

module.exports.routes = routes([all, contactsRoutes]);
```

### 2. api/routes/ContactRoute.js

```
module.exports.contactRoutes = {'get /v1/contact': 'ContactController.index'}
```

Comment: That function joins all routes you have defined over other files, upvote for you mate.

Answer (score 0):

You can require your another routes file in the config/routes.js and merge it with main using lodash (https://lodash.com/docs#merge)

```
var otherRoutes = require('/path/to/otherRoutes');
var routes = {
  'initialRoutes' : 'here'
}
_.merge(routes, otherRoutes);
module.exports = routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I come from a dot net background and there Attribute routing allows users to specify explicit routes in the controller itself. This is very useful feature as When you work with a team, you cannot have one large file which keeps on growing as it increases the conflicts when code is maintained on GIT.

So i wanted a similar solution in my sails app

I did it as follows

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var routes = {
    'get /test':'SiteController.testme'
};
_.assignIn(sails.config.routes,routes);

module.exports = {
    testme : function(req,res){
        res.json("I have been tested");
    },
    findOne: function(req,res){
        res.json("I have got one site");
    }
};
```

Here the controller name is SiteController